# Link marker to url Google Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Simple question:

Im trying to link my marker to an external url on a Google Map (API v3).
Can just use http://www.google.com as the link for now.

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.021664, 30.901578);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true
      }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('ContactMap'), mapOptions);
    var image = '/Assets/Images/Icons/MapMarker.png';

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: image,
          title: 'Perspex'
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: `link my marker to an external url ` means?

Comment: what you mean link? to open another link exactly on clicking the marker?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a google maps click `event` to the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

Do this immediately after defining `marker`.

Comment: Nice and easy! Thanks.